Next.js automatically resets tsconfig.json 'jsx' option, causing React import warnings in VS Code
I am working on a Next.Js-TypeScript project. Everything was fine. Suddenly I get a VS Code warning that I have to write import React from “react” in the .tsx files where I have used Fragment (<></>) of React. But everything was fine until yesterday. I suddenly saw this situation today. Then, I searched the internet and found that the “tsconfig.json” file contains (“jsx”:”preserve”) by default, but if I change it to (“jsx”:”react-jsx”) all the problems are solved. . But there is another problem here. When I start localhost or restart, immediately a message comes in the terminal, that We detected TypeScript in your project and reconfigured your tsconfig.json file for you. Strict-mode is set to false by default. The following mandatory changes were made to your tsconfig.json: - jsx was set to preserve (next.js implements its own optimized jsx transform). After that, the tsconfig.json file is reset as before.
This is my dependencies and devDependencies:
 "dependencies": {
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.7",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "mongoose": "^8.7.0",
    "next": "^14.2.13",
    "next-auth": "^5.0.0-beta.20",
    "react": "^18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.53.0",
    "react-icons": "^5.3.0",
    "react-player": "^2.16.0",
    "react-redux": "^9.1.2",
    "react-simple-star-rating": "^5.1.7",
    "react-toastify": "^10.0.5",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.79.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio": "^0.4.2",
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.6",
    "@types/node": "^20.16.10",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.10",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18",
    "@types/redux-persist": "^4.0.0",
    "daisyui": "^4.12.10",
    "eslint": "^8",
    "eslint-config-next": "^14.2.13",
    "postcss": "^8.4.47",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.4.13",
    "typescript": "^5.6.2"
  }

My tsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}


NOTE: THIS ISSUE IS HAPPENING WITH TYPESCRIPT ONLY!!

...your editor is wrong. In React 17+ you don't need React to be in scope to use JSX. I don't think this has anything to do with your tsconfig or Typescript, and the real question is why vscode is telling you that you need to import React. Do you have eslint misconfigured by chance?

I know this fact. That's why I wonder. I didn't change any settings. It is coming very quickly. All my projects are like this. I think this is a problem with VS Code.I restarted my code editor like hundred times but nothing happened. This word is being written on each React Fragment ' 'React' refers to a UMD global, but the current file is a module. Consider adding an import instead.ts(2686)

I'm having the same issue. In my case, vscode using dev version, so I switched to workspace version. You can do that by opening any typescript file -> click on {} on status bar -> click "Select Version" next to Typescript version -> select "Use workspace version"

In my case I found the solution to this strange problem. After I uninstalled the extension "JavaScript and TypeScript Nightly" from my VS Code everything was fine. Thank you so much guys


If I'm change the TypeScript Version to 5.6.2 (my workspace version & current stable) in VSCode the error is gone... When I go back to TS 5.7.0-dev.20241001 the umd global error comes back.
I would recommend to use a stable ts version, until its supported with newer ones.

It worked for me. Deleting the extension makes the warning go away.
I think the extension is not respecting package.json typescript version(I have used 5.6.2 but the bug is ocurring in 5.7.0 nightly version)
